# How can I refresh CSS caching?

Tags: css, asp.net, browser-cache

I already attach query string to my url

```
 "~/App_Theme/cssstyle/default.css?v=1"
```

but the style on the page was still not updated. In my IE's developer tool on css tab show both css file. 
How can I fixed this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share your complete markup? I think you are referencing the same CSS from two different locations, maybe from master page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you make a change and want to force the browser to fetch the latest version, you need to update the number on the end of your path, so something like:

```
"~/App_Theme/cssstyle/default.css?v=2"
```

then

```
 "~/App_Theme/cssstyle/default.css?v=3"
```

etc. The number can be anything, it doesn't need to be sequential. It just tells the browser that a different version is required.

In your case, your changes are not visible because you are specifying a particular version of your file. If you remove the version number parameter from your path, then clear the cache, you should see your changes:

```
 "~/App_Theme/cssstyle/default.css"
```

You can also press `Ctrl+F5` to force the browser to do a 'hard refresh', which re-fetches all assets.

As a last resort (and a good habit to get into if you're developing) is clearing the cache regularly. In most browsers, you can do this with `Ctrl+Shift+Del`. You can also do this automatically in Chrome by selecting `Disable cache (while dev tools are open)`, and leaving the dev tools open with `F12`

Comment: Thank you. I just forgot to change query string once again.

Comment: No problem, this one is burnt into my brain after thinking there was a server caching issue with my hosting provider for months! Definitely a lifesaver

Comment: Not sure if you are using Chrome, but in case you are, there's a setting that you can activate to disable cache when the Developers Tools Panel is open. This IMH is the easiest use case.

Answer (score -2):

In most browsers it is Ctrl+F5, (on windows)

Comment: Minus one because he was asking from a developer perspective not from a user perspective...

Comment: Fair enough, but the question was not really clear, (to me), if it was from a developer or user point of view.